# react native/expo go: undefined error when trying to open app on iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, undefined

I'm currently doing an tutorial where you integrate AI into an react native app. I?m struggling since 2 days because of an error I get when I try to open the app with the Xcode simulator. I always get the "render error: cannot read property of undefined". As the code is just a template from a tutorial and in general is its like a "copy code"-app for beginners (its my first time using react/ expo go) I think the app should work if you follow the tutorial instructions. I did that three Tims to make sure its not a mistake on mysid but still I cannot open the app as I get these errors and I don't know how to resolve them.

Below I provide some screenshots of the error message I get when trying to open the app in Xcode. Would be really grateful if someone maybe could help me or just give hints on what I'm doing wrong atm. thxxx

(It's a free sap tutorial on their sap ai core but the mobile app can also be launched without the ai integration and that what I'm trying. here would be the open GitHub for the mobile app: https://github.com/SAP-samples/smart-co2nverter-ai

I get the following error messages:

1.)
ERROR  [TypeError: Network request failed]
LOG  [TypeError: Network request failed]

2.)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CO2Score' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CO2Score' of undefined

3.)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

4.)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

It's my very first project using react native etc (I started my computer science journey few months ago) but I still don't get why these objects are undefined. Moreover the code I'm using is from the linked tutorial and (at least I assume) should work perfectly fine. But I already copied the code three times and added my credentials but I still get these error messages every time....

Very thankful if someone maybe has an idea on how I can resolves these errors.

It's my very first project using react native etc (I started my computer science journey few months ago) but I still don't get why these objects are undefined. Moreover the code I'm using is from the linked tutorial and (at least I assume) should work perfectly fine. But I already copied the code three times and added my credentials but I still get these error messages every time....

Very thankful if someone maybe has an idea on how I can resolves these errors.